# MongoDb.Driver 2.4 deserilization data type changing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb.driver

I have the following POCO class:

```
class MyClass {
    public Objectid _id {get;set;}
    public string property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}
    public int property3 {get;set;}
}
```

The object is stored in the MongoDb collection.  The data has the correct data types in the resulting bson:

```
property1: "SomeString"
property2: "12345"
property3: 98765
```

When I attempt to query the collection:

```
var items = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClass").AsQueryable().Select(x => x.property1 == "SomeString").ToList();
```

I get an error indicating that property2 could not be deserialized:
Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Int64'

I am trying to deserialize a string value from the bson document in the DB to a string value on my object.

**Why is the BsonSerializer trying to convert it to decimal?  In this instance, the value happens to be numeric, but the field is defined in the class as a string because the value is typically alphanumeric.**

I'm using the MongoDb.Driver v2.4 package, in VS2013.

Comment: Collection 'MyClass' in field 'property2' contains values with type int64. You can update datatype using javascript directly in Mongo console. I think c# driver doesn't support the same feature.

Answer (score 2):

For a Mongo property type change you need to write your own Serializer for that property.

This is the original object and you have saved several of these objects to Mongo.

```
public class TestingObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int TestingObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

Now we need to change the TestObjectType from an int to a string

This is our new class

```
public class TestingObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string TestingObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

You will then get the

> Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Int64'

What you need is a serializer to handle the conversion for you.

```
public class TestingObjectTypeSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
    public Type ValueType { get; } = typeof(string);

    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Int32) return GetNumberValue(context);

        return context.Reader.ReadString();
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value as string);
    }

    private static object GetNumberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context)
    {
        var value = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                return "one";
            case 2:
                return "two";
            case 3:
                return "three";
            default:
                return "BadType";
        }
    }
}
```

The key part is the Deserialize method.  Only if the type is int32 do you want to run your conversion logic.  If the type is a anything else we will assume it is already a string and return that value.

The Serialize just WriteString out and any document either updated or saved will have the new value as a string.

Now you just have to update your object to tell the property to use  your Serializer

```
public class TestingObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(TestingObjectTypeSerializer))]
    public string TestingObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

Next time you read it from Mongo you should not get the error.